# Another version of the command \triangleleft in amssymb

Tags: symbols, amssymb

I need the triangleleft symbol   underlined like the symbol `\leqslant`. 
Thank you all! [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a slanted bar, you can use picture mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\trianglelefteqslant}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\al@tlles\relax}}

\newcommand{\al@tlles}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$#1\m@th\leqslant$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}% \leqslant is essentially square
  \raisebox{-\dp\z@}{%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \roundcap\roundjoin
    \polygon(0.875,1)(0.125,0.625)(0.875,0.275)
    \polyline(0.125,0.375)(0.875,0.025)
    \end{picture}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A<\leqslant\trianglelefteqslant$

$\leqslant_{\leqslant}\trianglelefteqslant_{\trianglelefteqslant}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Font `stmaryrd` provide four such symbols:

[image]

Another possibilities is font `mathabx`:

[image]

and font `boisik` (see table 135, the same document).

Source: "The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List", Scott Pakin `scott+clsl@pakin.org`, 30 November 2015, page 66.